# qt use QNetworkAccessManager couldn't get the error signal

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

```
    m_request.setUrl(pDownloadInfo->url);
    m_preply = pManager->get(m_request);

    QObject::connect(m_preply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
            this, SLOT(DownloadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    QObject::connect(m_preply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(ReadyRead()));
```

I use qt5.0 and I use QNetworkAccessManager  to download the http file.
I couldn't get the error signal when I input a wrong url which didn't correct,
but I can get the finished signal when I input a correct url.

What's reason about this question?

Comment: 1) Check the first `connect`'s return value. 2) Put `connect` calls before `get()` call.

Comment: @Riateche 2) is not possible since `get()` allocates the `m_preply` pointer. And anyway, `QNetworkAccessManager` won't start anything before you return control to the event loop.

Comment: But I can get the finished signal,that may means I return control to the event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QNetworkReply` error signal is only for networking layer not protocol layer. It means that it will report all errors that occured during estabilishing connection with HTTP server. When connection is estabilished you won't receive `error` signal if HTTP server handled it correctly. Even if url you typed produced HTTP errors from 4xx or 5xx status codes still your reply will end without error (network error) as server handled your request.

If you want to handle HTTP errors you must use reply attributes with [QNetworkReply::attribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#attribute) method and handle them separately from errors that were reported with `error` signal

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it help me. I also want to ask if the QNetworkAccessManager not work in main thread, how could I get the signal.Now I put QNetworkAccessManager into a QThread, that make me can't get any signal.Some people tell me QNetworkAccessManager must work in eventloop? What should I do?

Comment: Your question is not directly related to your current problem. You should create new question about your threading problem with QNetworkAccessManager